# Add class to tag name

Tags: javascript

I want to access the direct children of element a with the tag h1( the first two h1) . I' ve done it like this :

```
var h =a. getElementsByTagName('h1');
```

And after that I have to add a class to those h1 which don't have a class attribute . How can I do this ? 
I thought of something like :

```
 if (h.classList.contains(NULL) == true)
     h.classList.add('class');
```

This is the html body :

```
  <body>
          <a> 
           <h1></h1>
           <h1></h1>
           <div>
                <h1></h1>
           </div>
        </a>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like that:

```js
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

    // No fancy forEach
    for (var i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
        if (h[i].classList.length === 0) {
            h[i].classList.add("class");
        }
    }
```

```css
.class {
  color:red;
  }

.some_class {
  color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<body>
<a>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1 class = "some_class">Heading 2</h1>
    <div>
        <h1>Heading 3</h1>
    </div>
</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! It does select the <h1> without a class tag . But for your example I don't want "heading 3 " to be coloured red . (His direct parent is <div>) . I want to do this for direct children of <a> .

Comment: var h = document.querySelectorAll('a > h1');

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like structure containing all elements that match the name, in this case all `<h1>`. You need to loop through it to access each `<h1>`.

Comment: Oh, so I've done it wrong. I only want to access the first 2 <h1> .

Answer (score 1):

Using this selector, you will select the first and second child of any anchor **but** will ignore the 3rd, 4th, etc. h1 child.

```
a > h1:nth-child(-n+2)
```

Snippet 1 demonstrates the use of this selector with `querySelectorAll()`. If you need the logic of:

> If first or second h1 **does** have a class then don't assign a class.

See Snippet 2 below.

#### SNIPPET 1

```js
/* Collect all first and second h1 that are direct descendants 
(i.e. children) of any anchor and put them in a NodeList.*/
var x2H1 = document.querySelectorAll('a > h1:nth-child(-n+2)');

// Total number of h1 in NodeList x2H1
var xQty = x2H1.length;

// Declare increment variable for 'for' loop
var i;

// 'for' loop will add the class .firstTwo to each item in NodeList
for (i = 0; i < xQty; i++) {
  x2H1[i].classList.add('firstTwo');
}
```

```css
.firstTwo {
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a>
      <h1>H1</h1>
      <h1>H1</h1>
      <div>
        <h1>Nested H1</h1>
      </div>
    </a>
  </header>
  <a>
    <div>
      <h1>Nested H1</h1>
    </div>
    <h1>H1</h1>
  </a>
  <section>
    <a>
      <h1>H1</h1>
      <h2>H2</h2>
    </a>
    <h1>H1 descendant of section</h1>
  </section>
  <a>
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <h1>H1 third child of anchor</h1>
  </a>
```

> **Note:** For simplicity, `classList.add()` was used instead of seeing if the h1 had a class. If for some reason you need to add a class to a h1 **but** not add a class to a h1 that does have a class, (as the logic is in OP's code) then use Snippet 2:

#### SNIPPET 2

```js
/* Collect all first and second h1 that are direct descendants 
(i.e. children) of any anchor and put them in a NodeList.*/
var x2H1 = document.querySelectorAll('a > h1:nth-child(-n+2)');

// Total number of h1 in NodeList x2H1
var xQty = x2H1.length;

// Declare increment variable for 'for' loop
var i;

/* 
'for' loop will:
  1. Determine if h1 has a class already
  2. If it does, then it is logged in 
  the console as being so.
  3. if not, then it will add the class
  .firstTwo to it.
*/
for (i = 0; i < xQty; i++) {
  x2H1[i].getAttribute('class') ? console.log('Already has a class') :
    x2H1[i].classList.add('firstTwo');
}
```

```css
.firstTwo {
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a>
      <h1 class='skip'>H1</h1>
      <h1>H1</h1>
      <h1>H1</h1>
      <div>
        <h1>Nested H1</h1>
      </div>
    </a>
  </header>
  <a>
    <div>
      <h1>Nested H1</h1>
    </div>
    <h1>H1</h1>
  </a>
  <section>
    <a>
      <h1>H1</h1>
      <h2>H2</h2>
    </a>
    <h1>H1 descendant of section</h1>
  </section>
  <a>
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <h1>H1 third child of anchor</h1>
  </a>
```

Using `.getAttribute('class')` will actually detect the attribute class whether it is assigned a value or not. So if for example:

```
 <h1 class=''>H1 with class but no value</h1>
```

That would be determined as true as it would if as an example:

```
 <h1 class='klass'>H1</h1>
```

If you want to ensure that every class has a value then as Alexy S. has suggested is the way to detect whether a h1 has a class **with** a value. For example:

```
    if (x2H1[i].classList.length === 0) {
        x2H1[i].classList.add("firstTwo");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to explain me this !!

Comment: You're welcome. I provided a very specific selector, since you emphasised the importance of exclusively selection of all 1st and 2nd children h1 of anchors. Keep in mind should you have a 3 or more h1 under an anchor, only the 1st and 2nd h1 will be selected.